# Protecting Protruding watch glass

Tags: technology

I own a smartwatch which, for some odd reason has the glass sticking up slightly over the bezel. I've cracked one, and somehow, after 3 months, I'm getting a replacement.

I'd like to prevent it from failing again. I'd love to post an image, but the manufacturer's been so nice, once I yelled at em proper-like so...

The last time the watch seemingly cracked from the edge, no drops, so I assume it was compression damage

[image: Diagram of raised watch glass]

That edge is fragile. What would be my option for protecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some manufacturers make protectors  for their watches. There are also some after-market protectors as well. Do internet research, after contacting the manufacturer of your watch to inquire if they make one or can recommend someone that does, and see what's available.

[image: Clear watch protector]

Obviously, this will not fit your square watch, but you may be able to find one that does.

If unable at find a square, pre-made protector, you could use a clear o-ring around the edge and affix it with clear silicone. A slim bead on the underside should do it.

[image: clear o-rings]

Comment: It's round. My image fu sucks.  How well do they protect edges tho? A bumper might work but they mostly seem Apple watch centric

Comment: Actually that looks perfect.

Comment: Very well. Despite the one I linked being round, look how it covers all the edges.

Comment: Some many manufacturers make after-market Apple stuff. You are certainly not the first person to experience this problem with the bezel. Do some research and make some calls/emails. I bet you find one that will work or can be modified.

Comment: It's not Apple. It's by a smaller manufacturerer. I figure I can measure and find one, now that I know what it's called.

Comment: Riffing off of @Lifehack's silicone idea, I bet a clear o-ring of comparable size would work. Same concept but neater/cleaner. You could stretch it around the square bezel, attaching it to the glass with a bit of silicone. Once dry, it will stay put until you remove it and will leave no residue.

Comment: http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1NBVoIXXXXXXmXFXXq6xXFXXXU/silicone-font-b-o-b-font-font-b-ring-b-font-font-b-kit-b-font.jpg

Comment: Yeah. Getting the replacement in today. I know an oldschool watch repair place that might have bezel covers or o rings for keys

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - somewhat off-topic... but doesn't it feel weird when you have to wait for 2 people to approve your edit?  ;)

Comment: *sigh* Yeah, to be plebian is a pain ;)

Answer (score 3):

A small bead of clear [silicone rubber sealant](https://accessories.lazydays.com/silicone-rubber-clear-2-8-69-39-684-69-39?cid=52-0013-05&gclid=CjwKEAiA0fnFBRC6g8rgmICvrw0SJADx1_zAeNYt8TFRgtxuoCe7qo7VV-Yb_buZqnJ_FgNPsFFIoxoCz8Dw_wcB) around the edge might do the trick and still look nice. Just use a razor to remove it or clean up the edges after you apply it.